# Using "or" or "or-like" statements with Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

While tinkering around, I found out what my problem was with my last/current issue:
When using:

```
saveKey = gwdzd10q
saveKeyp = False

while [saveKeyp == True,str(saveKey(2)) == 'k']:
```

I get:

```
while [saveKeyp == True,str(saveKey(2)) == 'k']:
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`
```

Why is this, and how can I fix it? Is it due to the way I am trying to do an or statement? Or what?

Do not mind the part, `str(saveKey(2)) == 'k']` because I have one later on checking for several other keys, including "d"

Comment: Please don't link to code. Instead, post *relevant* code, but not so much that it hides the core issue. Ask a focused question related to your posted code.

Comment: We are programmers so (1) we want code (2) it should be right here in the question so we don't have to do that whole click thing and (3) it should be a short example of the problem not a huge code dump because we have short attention spans. Post a short, runnable example of the problem!

Comment: I changed the question, could you look at it now?

Comment: ``saveKey(2)``, where ``saveKey`` is a string, is meaningless - perhaps you wanted square brackets instead of parentheses there?  The whole thing is meaningless anyway - you have a ``while`` loop with a 2-element list as its condition.  It doesn't matter what the values of those two elements are - a non-empty list is a truthy value.  You might as well have written ``while True:``, it's an infinite loop either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that by

```
saveKey = gwdzd10q
```

you mean

```
saveKey = "gwdzd10q"
```

If so, the third character of that string would be `saveKey[2]` rather than `saveKey(2)`. This is a string already, so it is pointless to run it through `str()`.

The condition that you seem to be trying to express is

```
saveKeyp or saveKey[2] == 'k'
```

Since `saveKeyp` is Boolean, using `saveKeyp == True` is superfluous.

If you want a `while` loop controlled by this it would be:

```
while saveKeyp or saveKey[2] == 'k':
```

but in that case the body of the loop would need to modify either `saveKeyp` or `saveKey`, otherwise you would have an infinite loop.

Comment: No, I am trying to get "while saveKeyp or saveKey[2] == 'k' ", and yes I mean "gwdzd10q"

Comment: @RobM   I'll modify the answer then. It wasn't clear what your intention with the comma was.

Comment: Whelp, I am stupid! I had tried literally just using or there, but it hadn't worked, so I tried something else there. I literally danced around the answer without knowing it! Thank you @JohnColeman

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to use array syntax to get at the characters of saveKey:

```
while [saveKeyp == True,str(saveKey[2]) == 'k']:
```

Second, a non-empty list evaluates to boolean True. So you have set up an infinite loop here.

```
>>> bool([False, False])
True
>>> bool([False])
True
>>> bool([])
False
>>>
```